# Inline-blocks not in one like exactly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs on my page, that css: display: inline-block.

```
.utilitiesContent div
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ear5n8n/) (don't pay attention that it has cyrillic letters). As you can see it is like stairs, not exactly in one line. How can I make it to has the same height level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.utilitiesContent div
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

you are looking for `vertical-align` property, I used top , you can play around and see what you like best.

[updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ear5n8n/2/)

I strongly recommend using `width: 32%;`  `33%` is just cutting it pretty close , and can jump down to the next row in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

Inline block will by default put space between the elements based on the font size. If you reduce the font size to zero you can remove the spacing.

```
.utilitiesContent div
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:33.33%;
    font-size:0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Then just set the font size to the elements inside the inline-block element.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ear5n8n/6/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.utilitiesContent div
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:32.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="utilitiesContent">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgupkfau/1/)    just decrease width to 0.5% FROM 33% to 32.5%

```
.utilitiesContent div
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:32.5%;
}
```

Comment: this is failing in IE9 , don't know if anyone cares anymore